# DataBinding on Getter Only Property That Concats 2 variables

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged

I have the following classes

```
public abstract class Contact 
{
    public abstract string FullName { get; }
    public abstract string FullName_LastNameFirst { get; }
}

public class PersonContact
{
    private string firstName;
    private string lastName;

    public override string FullName => firstName + " " + lastName;
    public override string FullName_LastNameFirst => lastName + ", " + firstName;
}

public class BusinessContact 
{
    private string name;

    public override string FullName => name;
    public override string FullName_LastNameFirst => name;
}
```

These classes extend INotifyPropertyChanged (not shown) and include public properties wrapping the private variables that trigger `OnPropertyChanged`.

The question is if I bind in WPF to the `FullName` or `FullName_LastNameFirst` properties how can I have them update when either of the properties that they are wrapping are changed.

Answer (score 2):

When you change underlying private fields (`firstName`, `lastName` or `name` in `BusinessContact`) - call

```
OnPropertyChanged("FullName"); 
OnPropertyChanged("FullName_LastNameFirst");
```

WPF data binding will subscribe to `PropertyChanged` event of your object and will listen to change notifications of corresponding property. Since your property has no setter in which you can call `OnPropertyChanged` - you need to call it explicitly when any underlying data changes.

Answer (score 0):

You surely have properties for your Person. If you have a ForeName property you can implement it like:

```
private string _ForeName;

public string ForeName
{
    get
    { return _ForeName; }
    set
    {
        if (_ForeName != value)
        {
            _ForeName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(this.ForeName));
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(this.FullName));
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, a PropertyChanged event will be fired, if the value of ForeName is changed. You can make the LastName property similar.

An other solution is, if the person class listens to its own PropertyChanged:

```
public Person()
{
    this.PropertyChanged += this.Person_PropertyChanged;
}

private void Person_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == nameof(LastName))
    {
        this.OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FullName));
    }
    if (e.PropertyName == nameof(ForeName))
    {
        this.OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FullName));
    }
}
```

This second solution is useful if you have generated classes, and you cannot change the property setters. Then you can make a partial class, and handle the property changes.

Answer (score 0):

The answers from Evk and lvoros are technically correct.

However, you can save yourself from having to write all this boilerplate code by using the [Fody ProperyChanged](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged) library (available via Nuget).

A class written as

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string GivenNames { get; set; }
    public string FamilyName { get; set; }
    public string FullName => $"{GivenNames} {FamilyName}";
}
```

Will actually be compiled as

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    string givenNames;
    public string GivenNames
    {
        get => givenNames;
        set
        {
            if (value != givenNames)
            {
                givenNames = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("GivenNames");
                OnPropertyChanged("FullName");
            }
        }
    }

    string familyName;
    public string FamilyName
    {
        get => familyName;
        set 
        {
            if (value != familyName)
            {
                familyName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("FamilyName");
                OnPropertyChanged("FullName");
            }
        }
    }

    public string FullName => $"{GivenNames} {FamilyName}";

    public virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var propertyChanged = PropertyChanged;
        if (propertyChanged != null)
        {
            propertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Fody will automatically generate OnPropertyChanged() calls for any dependent calculated properties in addition to the direct property wrappers.

I'm not normally a fan of programs working by "magic", but Fody is my one expception.